# Location Permission not working as expected on safari browser

Tags: reactjs, iphone, macos, safari

When we are trying to fetch the location in safari browser for my website(which is under development as of now). We are getting popup(allow, don't allow) for location permissions. When i am allowing it is working fine But when i am disallowing first and then change it after going into preferences and change location permission for the website to allow and trying to fetch location for the user again on button click but is not working without reload.

I have tried in console also using below commented code but there also i am getting error and not able to get the location without reload.

Expected is it should work without reload if we are giving locations permissions by going to preferences for a website on safari browser.

Comment: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (locationData) => {
        console.log(locationData);
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);

Using this code to get location.

Comment: Where is said "below commented code"? You will get better answers if you show what you've tried, so we can make more specific, targeted advice looking at the code

Comment: @onlyphantom I am just trying to fetch user location from 

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (locationData) => { console.log(locationData); }, (error) => { console.log(error); } ); 

using above code.